# Error during installing SQL Server 2019 in linux server ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install SQL Server 2019 in my linux server ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I just follow the step that given by Microsoft [Linux Sql Server Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Install%20the%20SQL%20Server%20command%2Dline%20tools,-To%20create%20a&text=Import%20the%20public%20repository%20GPG%20keys.&text=Register%20the%20Microsoft%20Ubuntu%20repository.&text=Update%20the%20sources%20list%20and,for%20SQL%20Server%20(Linux).) But I got error when I try to do the second step which is Register the Microsoft SQL Server Ubuntu repository for SQL Server 2019. I run the command but this error appeared:

Error 1:

[image: Error 1]

```
root@capt:/home/frenclub/Downloads# sudo add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)"
```

Receives the error

> Error: '' invalid

Then I change the double quote to single quote but still I got error:

Error 2:

[image: Error 2]

```
root@capt:/home/frenclub/Downloads# sudo add-apt-repository '$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)'
```

Receives the error

> Error: '$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)' invalid

I already try to google for any possible solution but I still cannot find any solution for this issue. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Please don't post images of `text`, and especially not links to images. Paste the actual text in blockquotes or code fences.

Comment: There is something wrong. I was not able to install it on my machine either. I guess it's something temporary.

Comment: Just spun up a 16.04 container, and I can't replicate the problem. Again, `text` not images would be great. Wouldn't be surprised you have a bad character which we can't see in your image.

Comment: @Larnu i already update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I spun up a Container Running 16.04 and couldn't replicate this:

```sh
thom@neith:~$ lxc launch ubuntu:16.04 u1604-mssql
Creating u1604-mssql
Starting u1604-mssql
thom@neith:~$ lxc exec u1604-mssql bash
root@u1604-mssql:~# wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
OK
root@u1604-mssql:~# add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)"
root@u1604-mssql:~#
```

You could, however, try to other method of using `curl` and adding the repository manually.

```sh
root@u1604-mssql:~# add-apt-repository -r "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)" #You don't need this, but I am including a full script
root@u1604-mssql:~# #Add key if you haven't already
root@u1604-mssql:~# curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-prod.list
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   103  100   103    0     0    306      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   307
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019 xenial main
```

*Note these commands do not use `sudo`, as I am running as `root`.*

I can confirm that after running `sudo apt update` after both that the `mssql-server` package was found.

Comment: I try to add repository by using this command "add-apt-repository "$(wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2019.list)" " but i got an error. But I try add -r in the command and Im not facing any error. Can u explain why when I add -r there is no error appeared?

Comment: As I mentioned, @aj17 I couldn't repro your problem. The `-r` switch, however, was there to remove the repository you failed you add, as per the comment on that line: *"`#You don't need this, but I am including a full script`"*